# Matrix product in linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, linear-regression

I do not understand why $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T * (X^TX)^{-1}X^T = (X^TX)^{=1}*I$

I keep trying to work it out and I just don't see it. This equality shows up when [deriving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687310/variance-of-coefficients-in-a-simple-linear-regression) the variance formula for coefficient estimates in linear regression (we have to square $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$).

Would someone be able to show me/help really understand why this is true?

Comment: What do you know about $(AB)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Notice that in order for $(X^T X)^{-1}$ to make sense, $X$ must have linearly independent rows, no matter what dimensions it has

Comment: What I read earlier is that you can write that as $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ when both matrices are invertible, I think

Comment: Take a look at this, it will give you the answer you are searching for : https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/othogonal-complements/v/lin-alg-unique-rowspace-solution-to-ax-b

Comment: Use also associativity.

Comment: This is not correct. $X^TX$ is a square matrix. If it is invertible and its inverse can be multiplied by $X^T$ both on the left and on the right, then $X$ must be a square matrix. But then by cancelling out the two instances of $X^T$ in $(X^TX)^{-1}$ by the two instances of $X^T$ outside the brackets, the whole expression is reduced to $X^{-2}$, not $(X^TX)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in knowing the variance of the coefficients we have
$$
\boldsymbol{Y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\beta}X,\sigma^2 I)\
$$
and
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \boldsymbol{Y}
$$
then we need the variance of $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$.
\begin{align*}
Var(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} ) & = Var((X^T X)^{-1} X^T \boldsymbol{Y}) \\
& = [(X^T X)^{-1} X^T] Var(\boldsymbol{Y}) [(X^T X)^{-1} X^T]^T \\
& = [(X^T X)^{-1} X^T] \sigma^2 I (X^T)^T ((X^T X)^{-1})^T \\
& = \sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1} X^T X((X^T X)^{-1})^T \\
& = \sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1} (X^T X)((X^T X)^{-1})^T \\
&= \sigma^2 ((X^T X)^{-1})^T  \\
& = \sigma^2 ((X^T X)^{T})^{-1}  \\
& = \sigma^2 (X^T (X^T)^T)^{-1} \\
& = \sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1}
\end{align*}
using $Var(A\boldsymbol{Y}) = A Var(\boldsymbol{Y}) A^T$